# Ms-access how to filter with empty fields

Tags: ms-access

I have three comboboxes which apply a filter command.

The WHERE condition is this:

```
[size]=[Forms]![Table1]![sizes] And 
[Type]=[Forms]![Table1]![types] And 
[product]=[Forms]![Table1]![products]
```

So I want to apply filter when types or sizes fields are empty(no value is entered) and it still will filter records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is generate the SQL filter code every time any of your comboboxes fires the AfterUpdate event. Set all three to point to a private function that checks their values and generates your filter, then apply it. If any of them are null then simply do not add them to the filter.

It can also be done without VBA by using something like `IIf(IsNull(Forms]![Table1]![sizes]),"",""[size]=[Forms]![Table1]![sizes]")` instead of just `[size]=[Forms]![Table1]![sizes]` but it can get complicated managing the `ANDs` so it is better to use VBA.